# Jquery plugin Cloud Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery plugin cloud zoom v1.0.2 and when I do, right click -> View background image in firefox, I get Kohana (framework) error. During inspection, I came across following snippet of code

```
<div class="mousetrap" style="background-image: url("."); z-index: 999; position: absolute; width: 380px; height: 283px; left: 0px; top: 0px; cursor: move;"></div>
```

So, "." is creating problem because when I delete it from Firebug, the error disappears. Since, I don't have this code in my source code, hence, I am wondering how should I fix this. Following is the snippet of my code from source code file.

```
<a href='<?php echo $orgpic->getImageForWeb('original'); ?>' class = 'cloud-zoom' id='zoom1' rel="adjustX: 1, adjustY:-1">
                            <img border="0" src="<?php echo $orgpic->getImageForWeb('original'); ?>" border="1" width="380px" title="Zoomed Image">
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this bug, I have just overwritten the background image path on top of source code file.

```
.mousetrap{
            background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==') !important;
        }
```